Is an unobserved measurement represented by a mixed state?
If I take a $\vert +\rangle$ state and measure it in the $Z$ basis but do not look at the measurement outcome, how should I describe the state? Is it just a mixed state
$$\frac{1}{2}\vert 0\rangle\langle 0 \vert + \frac{1}{2}\vert 1\rangle\langle 1 \vert$$
Or should I think of it as an entangled pure state that is entangled with the measurement outcome?
It seems like in the second case, I preserve some coherences while the first case, I lose these coherences.

The answer to your first question is: yes, $|+\rangle \langle +|$ turns into the maximally mixed state $$\rho = \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle \langle 0| + \frac{1}{2}|1\rangle \langle 1|$$ by having a Z-basis measurement with unknown outcome.
So, no: it is not an entangled pure state. (btw: entanglement is a concept which is defined between two quantum systems. As far as I know, there is no concept of a state being entangled with a measurement outcome)
How to go about your first question in a general way:
Every physical process that a quantum system can undergo can be described via a map:
$$ \rho \to \sum_k E_k \rho E_k^\dagger $$
where $\rho$ is your density matrix and $E_k$ are called Kraus-operators and they satisfy $\sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k = 1$.
In case of a measurement with unknown outcome, the Kraus operators are the projectors onto the eigenspaces of the measurement basis. One Kraus operator for each measurement outcome (that is, for each eigenvalue).
This means in your case: a Z-basis measurement corresponds to the projectors $E_0 = |0\rangle \langle 0|$ and $E_1 = |1\rangle \langle 1|$. Plug these two Kraus operators with $\rho = |+\rangle \langle +|$ into the above formula and you will get the maximally mixed state as a result.

Thanks for answering! I asked a related question here and would appreciate your comment using the same map with Kraus operator treatment: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/38273/does-this-measurement-preserve-superpositions

Sure, I will post the Kraus representation for that problem if you edit the question accordingly (that is, to explicitly ask for the Kraus representation)

This depends a bit on what interpretation of quantum mechanics you like. An Everettian (many worlds interpretation) will probably tell you that the measurement is stored on a physical system that is now entangled with the qubit it measured.
In practice, we don't see that entanglement. That could easily be because the measurement device is large. If you've read the measurement device, then you'd be in the superposition too, so it's really large. That entanglement may be there, but unless you look correctly at the entire Hilbert space that's in the entangled state, if you miss even just one qubit, then everything will appear as a mixed state.
While it might be valid mathematically to describe the outcome using an entangled state, in practice, nobody does. Since we're never going to do an experiment on that massive system, we're effectively just throwing it away, which is equivalent to tracing it out, and all you get back is the density matrix of the qubit you measured. Remember that a density matrix can be used to give the best possible description of that system that you have access to. That sounds quite reasonable in this context! It doesn't necessarily mean that you have lost any coherences in these circumstances, just that you cannot access them. (Anything that you do in the future could lose them, of course.)

If you take a radically simplified model of measurement, you can represent the measurement device by some state $|M_?\rangle$ that evolves into $|M_0\rangle$ or $|M_1\rangle$ depending on the result. Then the evolution of the system upon measurement would be
$$
|+\rangle |M_?\rangle \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( |0\rangle|M_0\rangle + |1\rangle|M_1\rangle)
$$
which is indeed a pure entangled state. However, this model of measurement is unrealistic as it doesn't take into account decoherence. This would be a realistic description if you put the system together with the measurement apparatus into a nearly magical decoherence-proof box, or, more prosaically, put it into a spaceship far away from you. In the latter case the pure entangled state will be an appropriate description while the measurement event is still space-like separated from you.
But in a realistic scenario, where the measurement is done in a regular laboratory on Earth, decoherence will spread everywhere, engulfing you, the laboratory, the building, etc., resulting in a state like
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( |0\rangle|M_0\rangle|\text{you}_0\rangle|\text{lab}_0\rangle + |1\rangle|M_1\rangle|\text{you}_1\rangle|\text{lab}_1\rangle)
$$
So it doesn't matter if you look at the result of the measurement or not, you are entangled with it. Then if you want to describe the system alone you take the partial trace over the systems you ignore, obtaining the mixed state you wrote. Of course, if you do know the measurement result you don't take the partial trace, but instead condition on the appropriate branch of the superposition (you could also not condition and use the entire superposition, but that's rather unwieldy).

+1 Strictly speaking, a spaceship remains vulnerable to environmental decoherence due to interactions with the CMB, starlight, gas and dust particles of the interstellar medium, gravitational waves, cosmic radiation, interstellar magnetic fields etc. Instead, one could perform Hamiltonian simulation of the composite system consisting of the measuring device and the qubit in a large fault-tolerant quantum computer. Could still place it aboard a spaceship for spacelike separation.

I know, a spaceship might still decohere, that's why I specified the space-like separation. Keep in mind, however, that the result of the measurement must really be imprinted in the decohering medium, so CMB, gravitational waves, gas, and dust are not going to do anything. If you want it to decohere the easiest thing is to display the result of the measurement in a computer screen and let it be visible through a window, so starlight will decohere it.
